# How to make console log this variable?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

beginning programmer here. If your reaction is "really...?" yeah, really. Sorry.

Im trying to write a function which logs the table of variable a in the console. I would be able to change the table logged by changing the argument in the function.

It keeps giving me the error code `index.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:6)` no matter how I change the code.

Function:

```
    function table(a) {
  Let a = 3
  console.log(`1 * ${a}, 2 * ${a}, 3 * ${a}, 4 * ${a}, 5 * ${a}, 6 * ${a}, 7 * ${a}, 8 * ${a}, 9 * ${a}, 10 * ${a}`)
}

table(a)
```

Comment: `let` not `Let` js is case sensitive

Comment: More than that, you won't be able to declare `a` with the statement `let` because the param has the same name.

Comment: @Ele How would i go about correcting this?

Comment: Couple points to share here, firstly, back-ticks will convert everything to a string so it will not evaluate the expression. Secondly, if you actually want the evaluation of every expression then do something like `console.log(1 * a, 2 * a...)`

Comment: Learn to use your developer console, error should have been listed as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" Click on it takes you to that line. You can use tools like eslint, jshint, etc to point out errors in your IDE.

Comment: @epascarello that sounds like a good idea, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case-sensitive, so the statement `let`must be written in lower-case.  Likewise, what you really want to do is declare the variable `a` outside of function `table`.

```js
function table(a) {
  console.log(`1 * ${a}, 2 * ${a}, 3 * ${a}, 4 * ${a}, 5 * ${a}, 6 * ${a}, 7 * ${a}, 8 * ${a}, 9 * ${a}, 10 * ${a}`)
}

let a = 3;
table(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only expresion in curly braces preceded by a dollar sign (placeholder) are evaluated within a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Therefore if you want to log the result, you have to write :

```
console.log(`${1*a}, ${2*a},...`)
```

(you don't need template literals here but I guess your question was more about how to evaluate expression within them)
You also can create a loop and concatenate the result or push it in an empty array

```js
function table(a) {
 let table = [];
 let str;
 let i = 1;
 for (i;i<=10;i++){
   table.push(`${a*i}`);
 }
  str = table.toString();
  return str;
}

let a = 3;
console.log(table(a));
```